# How to read a file name and append the name to a new column in a csv file using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

As the question says the requirement, I am using ubuntu os. I need to get the file name which I have in a folder called **Sample_csv_files** each represents a file in the same format except the id, e.g.

```
agent_op_023jlafa45459a390-.csv
agent_op_3rjfigr837yw749jh-.csv
agent_op_f78jlajk7h6559a39-.csv
```

Here I need to get those IDs and add them in a new_column. If I take for example the **agent_op_023jlafa45459a390-.csv** file, then I should populate the new_column with the id alone, e.g.

```
x  | y | new_column
abc|xyz| 023jlafa45459a390
```

for the entire CSV file. Similarly I need to do this for the rest of the files.
Hope can understand the description above.

Anyone can help me to solve it out.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('/home/user/Downloads/Sample_csv_files/agent_op_023jlafa45459a390-.csv')
df1['filename'] = "agent_op_023jlafa45459a390-.csv"
df1['filename'] = df1['filename'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('agent-output').rstrip('-.csv'))
df2 = []
df3 = df1['filename'].append(df2)
print(df1.head(10))
df1.to_csv("/home/user/Downloads/sample_work.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: what code have you got that reads your csv file?

Comment: added my code i worked to get a filename as required.(single file)

Comment: Are you hoping to combine all of the CSV files into a single `sample_work.csv` file or just add the new column to each file?

Comment: @Martin Evans i just try to add new column to each file with the filename that is been with the id alone as mentioned as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `glob.glob()` to give you a list of all of the CSV files and then just extract the ID from each filename and add a new column. The file can then be updated as follows:

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
import os.path

for filename in glob('my/source/folder/agent_op*.csv'):
    id = os.path.basename(filename).lstrip('agent_op_').rstrip('-.csv')
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df['run_id'] = id
    df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Comment: how to rename the column name to 'run_id' instead of 'filename'?

Comment: Use `df['run_id'] = id`, I've updated the script

Comment: i used but i could not get updated in each file as run_id

Comment: It will not change an existing column that is already `filename`. You should run the script on a copy of the original files. To do that would need a different script.

Comment: may i know how to do it ??

Comment: Try adding: `df.drop('filename', inplace=True, axis=1)` before the `to_csv` line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228199/discussion-between-sowmiya-and-martin-evans).